# Why would declaring a clock_t type integer change my C program?

Tags: c

I'm actually able to isolate what's wrong with my program.

I can break the program by adding a line like:

```
clock_t a_clock;
```

It doesn't matter what I name this variable, just that it is type clock_t, and I declare it.

I do not necessarily have to assign anything to it, or even try to time my program.

Here is a pastebin to the whole program.
You can try compiling and running the program yourself.
It will calculate PI to some reasonable degree of accuracy if you take out the "clock_t a_clock" line:

http://pastebin.com/1jdyiKnR

Here was the incorrect calculation for PI, which my program output:

```
Here is my_init 3533980296
Skipped first 100 results
Calculating PI from random numbers
total_count 1610725872 c_count 78541369
x 0.071707 y -0.055589
Guess for PI = 0.195046 with 100000000 iterations
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message, and that link doesn't open for me, post the code in the question for that use the edit link.

Comment: First, this is C++, not C. `for (int counter = 0; counter < num; counter++)` isn't valid C code, unless they allowed it in more recent versions of the standard.

Comment: Compiled and ran on my machine (MinGW gcc 4.8.1 with std=c99 on Windows 7). It didn't work, but it didn't crash either.

Comment: @GiulioFranco, no, it's C. just C99 standard used

Comment: Works for me, compiled and ran on Linux: `gcc -std=c99 -lm main.c`

Comment: It works on ideone, if you reduce the number of iterations to 10 (time limit). The result is wrong, but it doesn't crash. I guess you need to provide a more accurate definition of "break the program".

Comment: For compilation issues, include exact error message (as @iharob requests) and also the compiler (with version) and platform.

Comment: I have changed the question from "Why does this break the program" to "Why does this give the wrong answer."

Both versions compile and run without catastrophic error. I'm just trying to time this program, and I've found that adding a clock_t type variable of any name throws everything off.

Comment: unrelated, but `uint32_t my_init = time(NULL)*(4063691633*time(NULL)
                        + 10000 * time(NULL) + time(NULL) * 7);` - rolling your own security?

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I'm just looking for variation in my seeds. There's no reason to think that line is particularly good, although someone else might call it a day for an RNG...

Comment: `time(NULL)` usually gives a number of seconds, so these almost always will all return the same value; so your expression is equivalent to `4063701640 * time(NULL) * time(NULL)`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well, it's actually close to 4 billion in a 32 bit int size, so it's overflowing and looping over in fun ways.

Comment: If it were 32-bit int size then my contraction is correct because unsigned arithmetic is well-defined to be modular. However I just realized it's actually 64bit int size. `4063691633` has 64-bit type. (decimal constants larger than `INT_MAX` become `long` even if they would have fitted in `unsigned int`, and similarly for `long` to `long long`). So yeah, the result might be different after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling it with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -lm test.c

test.c:59:9: warning: ‘total_count’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int total_count, c_count = 0;
```

(and a couple of another harmless warnings about unused code)

That is, you have `total_count` uninitialized, just set it to `0` and it will work as expected:

```c
 int total_count = 0, c_count = 0;
```

Remember that using an uninitizalied variable is undefined behaviour. The fact that the result changed by declaring an additional variable was just by chance.

Comment: Wow, my `gcc` doesn't display this warning. I only managed to find it using `cppcheck`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko: Oh, I forgot the `-O3`. That adds additional variable life analysis and allows for more warnings.

Comment: @rodrigo: Didn't know that, thanks. Btw, it also works with `-O2`, which is more robust and reliable optimization level.

Comment: @rodrigo: you also may want to add `-lm` as this program compilation won't work on some systems (like my Debian testing) without specifying explicitly linking with `libmath`. But I'm not sure if it would be correct on Windows machine, which author is using.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I'm using a mac! and I declare the math.h thing!

Comment: @Rentsy: Sorry, I must've been mixed you with some guy in comments who mentioned that he's using Windows 7 :) Also, just doing `#include <math.h>` isn't always enough, sometimes you need to link with `libm.a` explicitly, providing `-lm` option to your linker (or `gcc` for that matter). Sometimes it's not necessary. So best approach here is to always do that, when you are using some stuff from math library.